# Apex trigger causing lead auto-response rule to fail

Tags: apex, trigger, leads

I have an issue with an auto-response rule that isn't working in our live environment (but does work in our sandboxes).  The lead auto-response rule doesn't fire even though the simple criteria is fulfilled (a hard-coded value on the web to lead form).

Upon disabling the following trigger, the auto-response rule works ok.  When enabled, the trigger works as expected but the auto-response doesn't get sent.  Can anyone see any issues with my trigger?  Its purpose is to set the Sales region based on the specified country (from a drop down).

```
trigger Lead_UpdateSalesRegion on Lead (after insert, after update) {

    List<Lead> leadList = new List<Lead>();

    for (Lead ld : trigger.new) {

        // use the custom settings to find the region for the country entered.    
        If (ld.Country != null && CountryRegionList__c.getInstance(ld.Country) != null) {

            String oldCtry;

            if ( trigger.isUpdate )  {                
                Lead oldLd = trigger.oldMap.get(ld.id);            
                oldCtry = oldLd.Country;
                System.debug('Old Country: ' + oldCtry);
            }

            String salesRegion = CountryRegionList__c.getInstance(ld.Country).Region__c;
            if (salesRegion != null && ld.Country != oldCtry) {

                Lead newLead = new Lead(id = ld.id, Sales_Region__c = salesRegion);
                leadList.add(newLead);

            }

        }
    }

    if(leadList.size()>0) update leadList; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce have advised "that when using triggers and auto-response rules it is always better to use this piece of code to trigger it manually."

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm